# How to change wrong icon from Unity launcher and Dash?

Tags: unity, icons, quickly

I am developing a software using Quickly. I have changed the icon but unity is still showing the old default icon even after I log out and log in back.
I have installed a .deb file of the software and it contains the new icon. I have even checked the .desktop file, which points to the new icon.

**How to change the icon from Unity's memory?**

I, however, am not sure whether this is Unity only.

Comment: Do you mean the old icon persists *after* you logged out/in?

Comment: Yes the old icon persists after log out/in

Comment: silly question, but do you have a copy of the .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`? (old version)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have found a copy there. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, when the `Icon=` line is changed in a `.desktop file`, it should be visible in the launcher after log out/log in. When an application is re- installed its icon should change as well, there is no "Unity memory" as you mention it.

#### Priority of .desktop files

Another thing is that a local version of a `.desktop` file (in `~/.local/share/applications`) has priority over the global one in `/usr/share/applications`. Since you mentioned having an (old) local copy of your `.desktop file` (in a comment), your newly defined icon in the global `.desktop` file only takes effect after you removed the local `.desktop` file.