# 16.04 How to get Unity to display new launcher file

Tags: unity, launcher

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

I went to ~/.local/share/applications .  I have a file in this directory named "eclipse.desktop" to run a particular version of Eclipse, which corresponds .  I copied the file to a new file with a different name. I changed the name and path properties in the file.  I saved the file.

At this point, I expected a new launcher to display in the Unity panel on the left side, to go along with the other launchers corresponding to files in that directory.  Nothing new is appearing there, even after saving the file.

Are my expectations incorrect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

Comment: No. Nothing I tried there made any difference.

Comment: I will investigate the use of "gnome-panel".

Comment: After going through all of that, I see that what this produces is a desktop icon. What I need is a Unity launcher icon, not a plain desktop icon.

Comment: Dragging the desktop icon to the Unity bar sort of works, but the icon changes from what I set it to to the default launcher "spring" icon.  How do I edit that to set it to the icon that I want?

Comment: Not a Unity user, but https://www.google.com/search?q=Change+Unity+launcher+iconoffers multiple suggestions. https://askubuntu.com/a/545016/197910 looks especially relevant.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I can't even get it to render the launcher that I stored in ~/local/share/applications. I had two in that directory before, which render fine, but the new one just seems to be ignored. The files are identical except for the "Name" value and the paths in the "Icon" and "Exec" properties. I did manage to get a launcher for it by first creating a desktop icon using "gnome-panel" and then dragging that to the launcher panel, but I can't set the icon I want.